# MySQL multiple output into one row

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following code:

```
select case when a.questionid = 184 then a.text end 'Assistant Name', 
a.questionid 'Question ID', 
case when (a.questionid = 125 and a.optionid = 1309) or (a.questionid = 135 and a.optionid = 1298) then 'Yes' else '' end 'Labelling Mentioned', 
s.outletid 'Outlet ID', 
s.visittime 'Visit Time'
from answer a inner join answerset s on s.id = a.answersetid
where s.VisitTime between '2014-03-01 00:00:00' and '2014-03-31 23:59:59'
and a.questionid in (125,135,184);
```

which produces output such as:

```
Assistant Name  Question ID Option ID   Labelling Mentioned Outlet ID   Visit Time
NULL    135 203         307     03/03/2014 09:37
Alf     184 NULL        307     03/03/2014 09:37
NULL    125 107         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    125 162         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    125 1309    Yes 26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 204         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 1298    Yes 26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 167         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 203         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 204         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 1298    Yes 26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 204         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 1298    Yes 26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 167         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 129         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 173         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 204         26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    135 1298    Yes 26888   03/03/2014 09:42
Steve   184 NULL        26888   03/03/2014 09:42
NULL    125 107         297     03/03/2014 09:46
NULL    125 198         297     03/03/2014 09:46
```

my problem being that I need to produce one row of output for a given outlet.  The required output would be "Assistant Name ¦ Labelling Mentioned ¦ Outlet ID ¦ Visit Time" with the assistant's name given, and a "Yes" if any of the "Labelling Mentioned" options contained a "Yes".

Is there a way this can be done?  I have tried a few things (grouping, COALESCE), but seem to have hit a brick wall.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). For a more specific answer you will need to post the relevant table schema and/or a [sqlfillde](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Thanks - will give it a whirl.